# How to disable button while AlphaAnimation running

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to disable click on button when the animation running.
the code is below:

```
    AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(4000);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    btnTag.startAnimation(anim);
```

So i want to cant click the button until animation done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally accomplish something like this is using an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html). It allows you to run code at various stages of the animation.

This code is untested, but the way it should look is:

```
AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(4000);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        btnTag.setClickable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        btnTag.setClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
});
btnTag.startAnimation(anim);
```

Not sure if btnTag is your button or a view holding your button, but call the button's `setClickable(boolean clickable)` method to enable and disable the button.

Comment: Is there a difference between setEnabled and setClickable?

Comment: If you want the button to look 'greyed out' until the animation is over then use enabled. The only real difference is that disabling removes onclick and gives the button a disabled look while clickable removes the onclick functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the solution I found for this problem, for those who use data-binding:

```
    binding.ivImage.setOnClickListener {

        binding.ivImage.animate().apply {
            duration=1000
            scaleXBy(.5f)
            scaleYBy(.5f)
            rotationYBy(360f)
            translationYBy(200f)
        }.withEndAction {
            binding.ivImage.animate().apply {
                duration = 1000
                scaleXBy(-.5f)
                scaleYBy(-.5f)
                rotationXBy(360f)
                translationYBy(-200f)
            }
        }
    }

  binding.ivImage.animate().setListener(object: Animator.AnimatorListener{
        override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {
            binding.ivImage.isClickable=false
            binding.ivImage.isEnabled=false
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {
            binding.ivImage.isClickable=true
            binding.ivImage.isEnabled=true
        }

        override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {
            binding.ivImage.isClickable=true
            binding.ivImage.isEnabled=true
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })
```